# Listen to modal dismiss in ionViewCanLeave

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to present a modal during route change for a form, but getting stuck with how to return the result to ionViewCanLeave.

```
ionViewCanLeave(): boolean {
    debugger;
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(this.cancelModal);
    let returnStatement = null;
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      debugger;
      returnStatement = data;
    });
    modal.present();
    if(returnStatement !== null ){
      return returnStatement;
    }
  }
```

How would I wait for onDidDismiss to trigger before calling the return statement for ionViewCanLeave?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better change your pattern to do what you want.

As fas as I know there is no way to stop `ionViewCanLeave()` returning.

Thus, make another function which asynchronously executes **leave page function** after **modal onDidDismiss** like the below.

```
checkCanLeave(){
  debugger;
  let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(this.cancelModal);
  modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
    debugger;
    // Put on your leave page function like 'this.navCtrl.pop()' orr 'this.viewCtrl.dismiss'
  });
  modal.present();
}
```

Comment: I ended up using async/await on ionViewCanLeave() as suchasync ionViewCanLeave(){
    if(this.submitted){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      const shouldLeave = await this.confirmLeave();
      return shouldLeave;
    }
  }

Comment: Yes, that seems correct way. I have just glanced at `view-controller.ts` in github. And I find it out ionViewCanLeave to be able to return `boolean | string | Promise<any>`.